# Correct way to run distributed training in ML Engine

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

Im trying to train my model (that is not build with tf.estimator or tf.keras) using distributed training job in ML Engine.

What steps should i take in order to run distributed training job in ML Engine?

I found following guidelines:

- provide `--scale-tier` parameter, from [step-by-step guide](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/getting-started-training-prediction)
- use distributed strategy API in the code, from [recent google io talks](https://youtu.be/bRMGoPqsn20?t=13m53s)

So if former provided in the command line does it mean i don't need to do anything with latter because ML Engine somehow takes care of distributing my graph across devices? Or do i need to do both?

And also what happens if i manually specify devices using:

```
with tf.device('/gpu:0/1/2/etc')
```

..and then run the command with `--scale-tier`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible scenarios:

**- You want to use machines with CPU:**

In this case, you are right. Using `--scale-tier` parameter is enough to have a job that is distributed automatically in ML Engine.

You have several scale-tier options {1}.

**- You want to use machines with GPU:**

In this case, you have to define a config.yaml file that describes the GPU options you want and run a gcloud command to launch the ML Engine job with config.yaml as a parameter {2}.

If you use `with tf.device('/gpu:0/1/2/etc')` inside your code, you are forcing the use of that device and it overwrites the normal behavior. {3}.

{1}: https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.jobs#scaletier

{2}: https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/using-gpus#requesting_gpu-enabled_machines

{3}: https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/using_gpu

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is it correct that in config.yaml i can specify kind of machines/devices i need: i.e. specific GPU devices? if so once it is done do MLE handles distribution of my graph between requested machines/devices? Or do i need to do it manually in some way? In other words, is adding config.yaml enough to run distributed training with MLE (like it works with CPUs) or do i need to do anything else?

Comment: Yes, it is enough to run a distributed ML Engine training, scale-tier parameter is for this purpose. By default, if you select GPU type machines, inner work using CPU, GPU or both should be automatic.You have to modify your code only in some situations when you want some code executed by a certain device.